# IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF (and should be)

Tags: c#, silverlight, linq-to-sql

I am trying to create a new row with data into a SQL table using Silverlight C# with Service Refrence. I get following error:

> `IDENTITY_INSERT` is set to `OFF`.

But I want the `Cart_ID` to be given automatically.

Table definition:

[image]
[image]

This is my C# code:

```
void createNewCart(String inpCartName)
{
    PositionServiceReference.PositionServiceClient service = new PositionServiceReference.PositionServiceClient();

    Lloyds_Cart newCart = new Lloyds_Cart();
    newCart.Cart_Date = DateTime.Today;
    newCart.Cart_Name = inpCartName;

    service.CreateNewCartCompleted += 
        new EventHandler<System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs>(service_CreateNewCartCompleted);
    service.CreateNewCartAsync(newCart);
}
```

My C# Operation Contract (Service Refrence):

```
[OperationContract]
void CreateNewCart(Lloyds_Cart newCart)
{
    PositionDataClassesDataContext context = new PositionDataClassesDataContext();

    context.Lloyds_Carts.InsertOnSubmit(newCart);
    context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Comment: Does your EDM know that it's an identity column?

Comment: why does identity have to be off?

Comment: Joe Enos: 
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Lloyds_Cart](
 [Cart_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [Cart_Date] [date] NOT NULL,
 [Cart_Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Lloyds_Cart] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED

Comment: Daniel A. White: So that two colums can have the same name, sepearted by diffrent IDs.

Comment: @Solo, Joe is specifically asking about the definition of the entity itself inside the data context.

Comment: You've not shown us any code related to data access, and that's almost certainly where the issue(s) lie.

Comment: In Management Studio navigate to table, right click, script table as->CREATE to->Clipboard. Then edit your post and paste :)

Comment: Agustin Meriles: http://pastebin.com/gvZKa3eH

Comment: Damien_The_Unbeliver: I have connection with database. I use a lot of information from database to print ships to the program on map... http://bildr.no/view/1413697

Comment: Can you show the code that defines the `Lloyds_Cart` class?

Comment: Andrei: The code that defines Lloyds_Cart is generated by C#... http://pastebin.com/cRn6tBNr
It was generated when I added the table to C# program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely property `Cart_ID` is not marked as DB generated in the context classes declaration. By default this property contains 0, Linq to SQL tries to insert this value into the corresponding column in DB and fails.

Make sure `ColumnAttribute` that decorates property `Cart_ID` has parameters `IsPrimaryKey` and `IsDbGenerated` set to `true`. You can also check it out in the designer in the Properties pane for `Cart_ID`.

**UPDATE** (after reviewing the context code): The `Cart_ID` property is missing `IsDbGenerated` parameter in the attribute, just as expected. Set it to `true` and everything should work.